# How to get Neighbour Node ID of single node based on node ID in Sigma js

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, sigma.js

I want to get all the neighbour nodes Id of particular node Id.

I know filtering based on filtering. But I dont want to filter the nodes, I just want to get the node Id of neighbours.

To filter I used this,

```
  filter
  .undo()
  .neighborsOf('node_id')
  .apply();
```

How can I display the node ID of above result without applying filters from my container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After surfing through internet I found it, I was looking for `sigma.plugins.neighborhoods.js`

Add this path in html,

```
<script src="plugins/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods.js"></script>
```

In Js add this below line,

```
db = new sigma.plugins.neighborhoods();
db.load('data.json', function() {
console.log(db.neighborhood('node_id'))
});
```